# Open a file in current directory

Tags: c++, file

I'm trying to open a file where my program runs, I could open a file in directories like this:

```
myfile.open("D:\\users.txt");
```

But I want to open this file:

```
myfile.open("users.txt");
```

users.txt is placed where my program is.

Comment: Does `./users.txt` work?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: That should work on Windows.  Have you tried it?

Comment: Remember that if this is Visual Studio the default folder for running or debugging is not the one that contains the .exe. It is the folder containing the solution file.

Comment: @drescherjm  Yea i was using vs thanks ...

Answer (score 5):

> users.txt is placed where my program is.

The current working directory of your process may not be where your program executable is. The two are not bound together.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
myfile.open("users.txt");
```

should work just fine. **However**, I have encountered situations where the program could not read the file. That was due to the white spaces being included within the full path:

eg: "C:\Folder1\Folder 2\file.txt"

Make sure you don't have any white spaces there...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading up on [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx) to give you a better understanding how Win32 API handles File paths, and also Namespaces. It will help you in the long run when you need to open USB and Serial connections to external devices.